# Gson: show class name when serializing a map

Tags: java, gson

I have a complex map to serialize, like

```
    Map<ClassA, Map<ClassB, Map<...>>>.
```

I used `GsonBuilder()` and added `enableComplexMapKeySerialization()`. It worked fine but it was like

```
    [{
        "foo": "bar"
        // data of A
     },
     [
        {
           // data of B
        }
        // other information
     ]
    ]
```

My question is, is there a way to add class name to the Json so it looks like

```
    [
     "ClassA": {
        "foo": "bar"
        // data of A
     },
     [
        {
           // data of B
        }
        // other information
     ]
    ]
```

Comment: Your second JSON output looks invalid. Arrays don't have property-names. You might be able to serialize to { "ClassA": { ... } }

Comment: Thanks. That was a mistake.

Comment: The output still looks invalid in the second case